# Putting blank space around nodes in a tkz-euclide grid

Tags: tkz-euclide

I want to draw a grid like this, with nodes 0 and X as shown, but with the grid lines broken behind each node. So the 0 and X are just on blank space.  How can I do that?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
\draw[step=.5cm,gray,very thin] (-1.4,-1.4) grid (1.4,1.4);
\draw (-1.5,0) -- (1.5,0);
\draw (0,-1.5) -- (0,1.5);
\draw (3mm,0mm) arc (0:30:3mm);
\node at (.5,.5) {\textbf{X}};
\node  at (0,0) {$0$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the option `every node/.style={fill=white}`::

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{xcolor}

```
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3, every node/.style={fill=white}]
\draw[step=.5cm,gray,very thin] (-1.4,-1.4) grid (1.4,1.4);
\draw (-1.5,0) -- (1.5,0);
\draw (0,-1.5) -- (0,1.5);
\draw (3mm,0mm) arc (0:30:3mm);
\node at (.5,.5) {\textbf{X}};
\node  at (0,0) {$0$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```